# Scan excel attachment cell(s) for specific text, and forward mail to correct recipient(s)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, attachment

I am new to using VBA and I adapted code I found online. I am attempting to search an Excel attachment within an e-mail, for specific strings of text in specific cells, and if it finds the correct text, to forward the mail to the correct person.

```
Sub CheckAttachments(olItem As MailItem)
Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\KoderM16\Desktop"
Const strFindText As String = "Car"
Const strFindText2 As String = "Toy"
Const strFindText3 As String = "Grass"
Dim strFilename As String
Dim olAttach As Attachment
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim MyItems As Items
Dim MyItem As MailItem

Set Inbox = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set MyItems = Inbox.Items
Set MyItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)   
Set MyItem = MyItem.Forward
If olItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
  For Each olAttach In olItem.Attachments
    If Right(LCase(olAttach.FileName), 3) = "xls" Or Right(LCase(olAttach.FileName), 4) = "xlsx" Then
      strFilename = strPath & Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd-HHMMSS") & _
                    Chr(32) & olAttach.FileName
      olAttach.SaveAsFile strFilename
      On Error Resume Next
      Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
      If Err <> 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        bXStarted = True
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0
      'Open the workbook to read the data
      Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFilename)
      Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
      If FindValue(strFindText, xlSheet) Then
        MyItem.Recipients.Add "emailaddress1"
        MyItem.Send
      ElseIf FindValue(strFindText2, xlSheet) Then
        MyItem.Recipients.Add "emailaddress2"
        MyItem.Send
      ElseIf FindValue(strFindText3, xlSheet) Then
        MyItem.Recipients.Add "emailaddress3"
        MyItem.Send
      End If
      xlWB.Close 0
      If bXStarted Then xlApp.Quit
      If Not bFound Then Kill strFilename
      Exit For
    End If
  Next olAttach
End If
End Sub

Function FindValue(FindString As String, iSheet As Object) As Boolean
Dim Rng As Object
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With iSheet.Range("B2")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=-4163, _
                        LookAt:=1, _
                        SearchOrder:=1, _
                        SearchDirection:=1, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FindValue = True
        Else
            FindValue = False
        End If
    End With
End If
End Function

Sub Test()
Dim olMsg As MailItem
  On Error Resume Next
  Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
  CheckAttachments olMsg
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `FindValue` function works for me (in that it only looks in cell B2).

Comment: Instead of the function you can also simply check `xlSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = strFindText` (or `LCase(xlSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value) = LCase(strFindText)` if you need case insensitivity)

Comment: Thanks Arcadeprecinct, that has helped simplify my code. However, i am still having the issue. Essentially I want this result:
If B2 = "Car" Then send mail to "Address1" End If
If A5 = "Toy" Then send mail to "Address2" End If
I have those above as 2 separate if statements written in the correct syntax however, as soon as it finds the first one it stops.

Comment: That's odd, remove the `On Error Resume Next` and see if you get any errors. Stepping through the code using F8 might also help

Comment: Please add an answer to your question (it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question) and remove the "solution" from your question.

Comment: @RobinDaugherty done as requested. But I am sure someone else will have a problem with how I've done it and will complain or change everything lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code searches the .xls attachment and if it finds the data in the sheet, it forwards the mail. However, I want to be able to point to multiple individual cells. There might be some unnecessary stuff in the code. I try to point to cell B2 near the bottom of the code but even if it finds the text in A1, it sends the mail.

```
'Section 1

Sub CheckAttachments(olItem As MailItem)
    Const strPath As String = "Enter_Path_Here" 'Define a path for the temp file
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim olAttach As Attachment
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim bXStarted As Boolean
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim MyItems As Items

    'Section 2

    'A new MyItem is required per mutually exclusive recipient as below

    Dim MyItem As MailItem
    Dim MyItemTwo As MailItem
    Dim MyItemThree As MailItem
    Dim MyItemFour As MailItem
    Dim MyItemFive As MailItem
    Dim MyItemSix As MailItem

    'Section 3

    Set Inbox = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set MyItems = Inbox.Items

    'Section 4

    'A new MyItem is required per mutually exclusive recipient as below

    Set MyItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    Set MyItem = MyItem.Forward
    Set MyItemTwo = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    Set MyItemTwo = MyItemTwo.Forward
    Set MyItemThree = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    Set MyItemThree = MyItemTwo.Forward
    Set MyItemFour = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    Set MyItemFour = MyItemTwo.Forward
    Set MyItemFive = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    Set MyItemFive = MyItemTwo.Forward
    Set MyItemSix = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    Set MyItemSix = MyItemTwo.Forward

    'Section 5

    If olItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        For Each olAttach In olItem.Attachments
            If Right(LCase(olAttach.FileName), 3) = "xls" Or Right(LCase(olAttach.FileName), 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(LCase(olAttach.FileName), 4) = "xlsm" Then 'Define the file types to search in
                strFilename = strPath & Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd-HHMMSS") & _
                    Chr(32) & olAttach.FileName
            olAttach.SaveAsFile strFilename
            On Error Resume Next
            Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
            If Err <> 0 Then
                Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
                Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                bXStarted = True
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            'Open the workbook to read the data
            Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFilename)
            Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

            'Section 6

            'A new xlSheet cell selection and If statement is required for mutually exclusive recipients as below. Multiple addresses can be added to one condition

            If xlSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Enter_Value_To_Find" Then
                MyItem.Recipients.Add "Enter_E-Mail_Address"
                MyItem.Send
            End If

            If xlSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Enter_Value_To_Find" Then
                MyItemTwo.Recipients.Add "Enter_E-Mail_Address"
                MyItemTwo.Send
            End If

            If xlSheet.Range("F1").Value = "Enter_Value_To_Find" Then
                MyItemThree.Recipients.Add "Enter_E-Mail_Address"
                MyItemThree.Send
            End If

            If xlSheet.Range("C10").Value = "Enter_Value_To_Find" Then
                MyItemFour.Recipients.Add "Enter_E-Mail_Address"
                MyItemFour.Send
            End If

            If xlSheet.Range("D5").Value = "Enter_Value_To_Find" Then
                MyItemFive.Recipients.Add "Enter_E-Mail_Address"
                MyItemFive.Send
            End If

            If xlSheet.Range("E7").Value = "Enter_Value_To_Find" Then
                MyItemSix.Recipients.Add "Enter_E-Mail_Addressa"
                MyItemSix.Send
            End If

            'Section 7

            xlWB.Close 0
            If bXStarted Then xlApp.Quit
            If Not bFound Then Kill strFilename
            Exit For
        End If
        Next olAttach
    End If
End Sub

Sub Test()
    Dim olMsg As MailItem
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    CheckAttachments olMsg
End Sub
```